# How to detect blank lines in a file while combing the data in this file with another set, then stop the loop is detected?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from itertools import zip_longest
with open("over_speeding.txt") as speeding, open("fine.txt") as fine, open("all details.txt", "a") as everything:
for speedline, fineline in zip_longest (speeding, fine, fillvalue=""):
    everything.write (fineline.strip() + "   ---   " + speedline.strip() +  "\n")
```

This code combines two files(speeding & fine) and write them into a new file (everything).

Fine is an already set file with 10 lines of data written in it, whereas the data in speeding file is appended into from another code. Sometimes when I enter the data from the other code, the data for speeding file could take up less than 10 lines.

So what I want this code to do, is to detect the first blank line in the speeding file then stop the for loop if the line is empty and have only the lines before the blank line written into the file everything.

e.g

fine.txt(already set file):

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx
aaaaaaaaaaa
ssssssssss
wwwwweeeee
uuuuuuuuuu
ooooooooooo
nnnnnnnnn
e.t.c.......
```

speeding.txt (file that gets data from the code):

```
111111111
999999999
```

everything.txt(where the data from both codes are appended to) should now look like:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx --- 111111111
aaaaaaaaaaa --- 999999999
```

rather than:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx --- 111111111
aaaaaaaaaaa --- 999999999
ssssssssss
wwwwweeeee
uuuuuuuuuu
ooooooooooo
nnnnnnnnn
```

#this is what my code is doing right now

Answer (score 1):

[kpie] has the right idea with using `break`. No need to load the whole file into memory, since OP is already iterating line by line. Instead add the condition to your existing loop:

```
for speedline, fineline in zip_longest (speeding, fine, fillvalue=""):
    if not fineline.strip():  # if fineline is empty or only whitespace
        break
    everything.write (fineline.strip() + "   ---   " + speedline.strip() +  "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the file with str.split("/n").

You now have list of lines of text.

You can itterate through that list and check if you are at a blank line.

```
for line in speeding.split(\n):
    if line == "":
        break
```

Comment: I already tried that it just showed an error message                        AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'